# Throwing a user-defined error message based on column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am trying to generate an error to give the user whenever there is a duplicated record. However, I need the error the tell the user exactly which district is duplicated.

How do I generate an error message based on where row_number is 2? I need the message to tell the user for example: which district is duplicated. I tried using the variable but could not figure out how to emulate the row_number.

```
DECLARE @DISTRICT NCHAR(12),
    @PLAN NCHAR(10),
    @CATEGORY CHAR(1),
    @RESULT NCHAR(1)

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @DISTRICT = DISTRICT, @PLAN = PLAN, @CATEGORY = CATEGORY,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY @DISTRICT, @PLAN ORDER BY                     @DISTRICT) = 2 THEN 1/0 END
    FROM TABLE1

    SELECT DISTRICT, PLAN, CATEGORY 
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DISTRICT, PLAN ORDER BY DISTRICT) = 2 THEN 1/0 END
    FROM TABLE1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE  VARCHAR(30) 

    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = 'FIX ERROR ON ' + @DISTRICT;

    THROW 50000, @ERROR_MESSAGE,1
END CATCH
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

| DISTRICT | PLAN | CATEGORY | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EAST | A | HEALTH | 1 |
| EAST | A | LIFE | 2 |
| WEST | A | MOTOR | 1 |
| WEST | B | MOTOR | 1 |
| WEST | B | LIFE | 2 |

Comment: Please show some sample data to illustrate the problem (as formatted text **not* images).

Comment: This smells like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and a probable dead-end. Firstly you enforce uniqueness with a constraint. Give your current struggle, you are likely to fail trying to do this in code. Secondly, you appear to assume that there is only 1 duplicate - usually that is not a safe assumption. Third, you can throw an error without forcing a divide-by-zero error - which is seems to be a kludge.

Comment: And if your first select statement (where you assign variables) returns multiple rows, the row used for the source of the assignment can be ANY row in the table (and I'll note you select EVERY ROW). That assignment is not deterministic. So again - I think you should start over and reconsider your current approach.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for your input. And you are correct, that assignment in the first select statement is not deterministic. I'll look into the constraints.